# Create global variable for authenticated user in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

In laravel 5.4 after logged in I can access `Auth::user()` in each controller. but I want to make it as global variable that can be use in all controllers and views.

After google I tested following codes.
1) AppServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{     
    View::share('currentUser', Auth::user()); 
}
```

But can not access in view.

2) app\Http\Controllers\Controller.php

```
private $user;
private $signed_in;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $this->user = Auth::user();
        $this->signed_in = Auth::check();

        view()->share('signed_in', $this->signed_in);
        view()->share('user', $this->user);

        return $next($request);
    });

}
```

But can not access in view.

can anyone help thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Hm, why not just stick to `Auth::user()`?

Comment: @kerbholz your question is right but I just want to keep a single word variable that can be use in several places. that's why I don't want to stick with the `Auth::user()`

Comment: @JulienLachal "not working" means that I can not access the shared variable for view as per the code sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution using second technique.

2) app\Http\Controllers\Controller.php

This controller is the basecontroller

```
private $user;
private $signed_in;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $this->user = Auth::user();
        $this->signed_in = Auth::check();

        view()->share('signed_in', $this->signed_in);
        view()->share('user', $this->user);

        return $next($request);
    });

}
```

I have to put following code `parent::__construct();` in each controller constructor.

**For example:**

```
class StatusController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');

        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Now I can access in the any view

```
{{ $user->user_id }}
```